# Where in ansible support for windows?

Tags: windows, ansible, ansible-facts

I try write yml for different systems.

in ansuble_os_family and ansible_distribution I don't see Windows.
how should I write condition for task for windows?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a windows machine `ansible_os_family` should have the value `Windows`. If this is not the case in your play, there seems to be some error. Maybe you should retest and make sure, you are actually targeting a windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

try with:
when: ansible_system == 'Win32NT'

Comment: This suggestion will work when windows is 32 bit .for 64 bit,again make a change to Win64NT?

Comment: Looks like there is no Win64NT: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.platformid. I also got Win32NT on 64-bit Windows.